# Dropdown list not populating from database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I seem to be having an issue. I have an input field and a `<select>` field. I need to type in a location in the input field and if that word matches a record in my database then it should the names of the people in my `<select>` drop down list. Here is my index.php file:

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<input type="text" name="location_input" id="location_input">
Tutor:<select name="locations" id="locations">
    <script> 
        $("#location_input").keyup(function(){
            const location = $("#location_input").val();
            $("#locations").html(''); //reset dropdown
            // do ajax call to get locations
            $.ajax({
                url: 'search.php',  //replace this with your route of the search function
                data: {location}, //pass location as body data
                dataType: 'json', //expect a json response back
                success: function(data) {
                    data.forEach(function(el) { //loop over the json response
                        let option = `<option id=${el.id} value=${el.name}>${el.name}</option>`
                        $("#locations").append(option); //append locations to select dropdown
                    });
                },
                error: function(err) {  //error functions
                    console.log(err);
                    alert("Error")
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

</select>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my search.php file:

```
   <?php
function SearchLocations() {
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'tutors') or die ('Cannot connect to db');
    $result = $conn->query("select * from tutor_location where Location_tags LIKE ='%". $_GET['location']."%'");

    $locations = [];

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $locations[] = $row;    

    }

    return json_encode($locations);

}

?>
```

And here is a screenshot of my database:[image]
The issue which I am facing is that it gives me a `localhost says error` and the console doesn't show me an error.

Comment: is it going inside success block

Comment: @brk no it is going into the error block and when i check the console it doesnt show anything

Comment: so your ajax is not successful and i think the issue is `data: {location}, `

Comment: @brk how would i resolve this issue

Comment: check how to pass data using ajax

Comment: @brk i cant seem to find an error anywhere

Comment: @brk `data: {location}` is completely fine.

Comment: @adis as far as i know it has to be a key value pair

Comment: @brk New in JavaScript with ES6/ES2015, if you want to define an object who's keys have the same name as the variables passed-in as properties, you can use the shorthand and simply pass the key name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try ajax like below request,

```js
$.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      dataType:"json",
      url: 'search.php',
      data: {order_numbers: values, order_state: status},
      success: function(response){ },
      error: function(response){}
    });
```

Comment: in the `   data: {order_numbers: values, order_state: status},` how do i tweak it to my needs?

Comment: var location_value = $("#location_input").val();
data: {location: location_value},

can you please try with this code may be this will solve your needs...

Comment: Ismail. You can continue our chat. You don't need to duplicate a question. There are many things wrong with your code. Firstly, you have the script tag inside a select element. Put it outside of it.